# How to use Dojo imageStore getValue?

Tags: javascript, dojo

First off, Im a total Dojo newb.  I just burned half a day trying to get a value from an imageStore for a thumbnailpicker.  I have failed miserably at google.  If anyone could help me, Id be greatly appreciative.

Heres what I have that doesnt work.

```
dijit.byId('thumbpicker').imageStore.getValue( 'dimensions');
```

There is a key called dimensions in my itemfilewritestore for the thumbnailpicker.  I can see it in firebug.  I just have no clue how to obtain it with dojo.  I cannot wait to get back to jQuery :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the ThumbnailPicker, but I think the problem is that the store's `getValue` method requires two arguments: the item and the name of the value you want. When you say: `imageStore.getValue("dimensions")`, the dimensions for which item in the store is it that you want? Assuming you have the item in a variable `target`, you actually have to do:

```
dijit.byId('thumbpicker').imageStore.getValue(target, 'dimensions');
```

Actually, the right way to get a property from a widget is to use the `get` method, so

```
dijit.byId('thumbpicker').get("imageStore").getValue(target, 'dimensions');
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was able to get me a value.  However, I realized the thumbnailpicker is a PITA so I just set up jQuery jCarousel in 10 minutes and called it a day.